# Evaluating $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \cos x\right) ^{\cot ^{2}x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, logarithms

This math has one trigonometric ratio as power of another trigonometric function.

> $$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \cos x\right) ^{\cot ^{2}x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering $$y=\big(\cos(x)\big) ^{\cot ^2(x)}\implies \log(y)=\cot ^2(x)\log(\cos(x))$$ use composition of  Taylor series
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$\log(\cos(x))=-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$\cot(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\cot ^2(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{3}+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$\log(y)=-\frac{1}{2}+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}+O\left(x^2\right)$$

If you want to see more, add one more term to each expansion; this would give
$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}+O\left(x^4\right) \right)$$ which, for sure, shows the limit but also how it is approached.

Moreover, this is a quite good approximation. Using $x=\frac \pi 6$ (this is quite far away from $0$), the exact value is $y=\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{8}\approx 0.649519$ while the last truncated expansion gives $\frac{144+\pi ^2}{144 \sqrt{e}}\approx 0.648102$ which corresponds to a relative error of $0.2$%.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Use that $$e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{\tan^2(x)}}$$

Comment: how to solve it in whole?

Comment: After this you must use the rules of L'Hospital.

Comment: OK.. Good that u gave the info.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$\lim_{x\to0}(\cos x)^{\cot^2x}=\left(\left(\lim_{x\to0}(1+\cos x-1)^{1/(\cos x-1)}\right)^{\lim_{x\to0}(\cos x-1)/\sin^2x}\right)^{\lim_{x\to0}\cos^2x}$$

Now $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos x-1}{\sin^2x}=-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos x-1}{\cos^2x-1}=-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac1{1+\cos x}=?$

Comment: how to solve it in whole?

Comment: Wow that's slick!

Comment: @Jency, Don't expect whole solution. Try to utilize the  standard limit formulas

Comment: Yes... I will...

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it as follows using $\lim_{t\to 0}(1-t)^{\frac 1t}=\frac 1e$.

Write $\cos x = 1 -2\sin^2 \frac x2$, so you get

\begin{eqnarray*} \left( \cos x\right)^{\cot x}
& = & \left(\underbrace{\left(1-2\sin^2\frac x2\right)^{\frac{1}{2\sin^2 \frac x2}}}_{\stackrel{x\to 0}{\rightarrow}\frac 1e}\right)^{\underbrace{\frac{2\sin^2 \frac x2}{\sin ^2 x}}_{\stackrel{x\to 0}{\rightarrow}\frac 12}\cdot \cos^2 x}\\
& \stackrel{x\to 0}{\rightarrow} & \frac{1}{\sqrt e}
\end{eqnarray*}